# Passing updated variable to RreactJS component but variable not updating correctly inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm passing a variable called rows to a component "Hello." If I remove that component and simply put "p" tags around {rows} it shows the variable updating correctly. However, when I pass {rows} to "Hello" it doesn't update right. Can someone explain some form of a solution to this please!

NOTE: this snippet is part of a bigger project. There is a state based on user selection that updates the "filterBy" variable. So I'm not sure this is a rendering issue based on change State cause rows is changing and updating.

Code Below:

```
    var Hello = React.createClass({
    rowMake: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.rows.map(function(row, index){
                    return(
                        <tr>
                            <td key={index}>{row.title}</td>
                            <td>{row.status}</td>
                            <td>{row.created_at}</td>
                            <td>{row.updated_at}</td>    
                        </tr>
                    );
                  })
                }
            </div>
        );
    },
    render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="container">           
                <table className="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Title</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Created</th>
                      <th>Updated</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{this.rowMake()}</tbody>        
                </table>
          </div>
          );
    }
});


//RequestTable creates the table head and body.

var RequestTable = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        requests = this.props.requests;
        filterBy = this.props.filterBy;
        var rows = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<requests.length; i++){
            if(filterBy == 'All'){
                rows.push(requests[i]);
            }
            else if(filterBy == 'Approved'){
                if(requests[i]["status"] == "Approved"){
                    rows.push(requests[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(filterBy == 'Denied'){
                if(requests[i]["status"] == "Denied"){
                    rows.push(requests[i]);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(requests[i]["status"] == "Pending"){
                    rows.push(requests[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return(
            <Hello rows = {rows} />
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you logged `this.props.rows`? And one more thing `tbody` won't have `div` as direct children. Refactor that

Comment: If you mean "logged" as in wrap {rows} before it is passed to "Hello" in p tags to see if it changes, yes I have. It updates. But for some reason when I pass it too the component and log it it keeps a lot of the old values and doesn't change properly. Only changes correctly if I don't pass to "Hello" component.

Comment: No I mean `console.log(rows)` in `Hello` component to see whether they are passing through props properly

Comment: Couldn't get console.log to work. So what I did was put "<p> {rows} </p>" inside the rowMake function and the variable was correct. It was updating. For some reason when I it's inside all that table stuff though it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I mean inside the "Hello" component render function.

Comment: Can you show your `rows` data and parent component of `Hello` component

Comment: It seems to be breaking inside my rowMake() function. If I "console.log" with the <p> tags it shows the weird behavior. On this first change the variable isn't updating. But if I change it one more time it seems to update appropriately. This seems to only happen inside the rowMake funciton. Also, if I remove the divs the function breaks and code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'll send you a JSFilddle.

Comment: That's fine, update in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/malbori/y4wyqg6r/562/

Comment: ignore 562 that is old. https://jsfiddle.net/malbori/y4wyqg6r/564/

Comment: It's working in your fiddle

Comment: It is? When I change the select option the table doesn't change or update from what I saw.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `rowMake()` function messing up there.

Removed the `rowMake()` method and updated the code in `render` method itself. Of course this is the better method when dealing with `list` of data which keeps updating with `DOM` events.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4wyqg6r/566/)

Comment: Omg... your awesome! Not sure why I didn't try to just do it that way to begin with. THANK YOU!!!